# Does yarn pin specific versions for dependencies of dependencies?

Tags: yarnpkg

Say we have a dependency X that itself has a dependency Y. X does not use yarn and does not pin a specific version of Y (i.e. X's package.json has `"Y": "^1.0.0"`). Does yarn allow us to pin and use a specific version of transitive dependency Y?

More context:
In our package.json, we pin the version of dependency X. But dependency X has an unpinned dependency Y (e.g. `"Y": "^1.0.0"`), which exports some .d.ts files. A new version of Y came out that used some new Typescript features, which suddenly broke our tsc compile with the version of Typescript we use in our package.json. There was no way for us to pin the version of Y in our package.json, so this issue was unavoidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Yarn pins the entire dependency tree, and guarantees determinism - you and your teammates will end up with the same exact versions of all dependencies (and all deps of deps) as long as you are using the same version of yarn. See https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/05/31/determinism/.